# Android ... Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android

I need a help. I'm trying to implement Custom camera using surface vie, but I'm stacked into this error:

```
Process: visionary.anselmo.camerademo, PID: 7464
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:496)
                                                                            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:360)
                                                                            at visionary.anselmo.camerademo.CameraActivity.surfaceCreated(CameraActivity.java:149)
                                                                            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:608)
                                                                            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:160)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2201)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

And the here goes the activity that handles this:
    public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Camera camera;
@InjectView(R.id.surface_view)
SurfaceView surfaceView;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_take_picture)
ImageView take_picture;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
ShutterCallback shutterCallback;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    // Install the surfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the underlying is created and destroyed
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    take_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraImage();
        }
    });
    pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            File imageFile = getDirectory();
            if (!imageFile.exists() && !imageFile.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Nao foi possivel criar o directorio para a imagem.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String date = format.format(new Date());
            String photoFile = "Demo" + date + ".jpg";
            String fileName = imageFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + photoFile;
            File picFile = new File(fileName);
            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
                outputStream.write(data);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            refreshCamera();
            refreshGallery(picFile);
        }
    };
}

 private void refreshGallery(File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

 private void refreshCamera() {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // Preview surfave does not exists
        return;
    }
    // Stop the preview before making changes
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    // Set the preview size, and make any resize, rotate or any reformmating changes here
    // Start preview with new Settings
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}

 private File getDirectory() {
    File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    return new File(dics, "CameraActivity");
}

     private void cameraImage() {
    // Take the picture
    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Open the fuck'n Camera here
    releaseCamera();

    camera = Camera.open();

    Camera.Parameters parameters;
    parameters = camera.getParameters();

    // Modify the parameters
    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    try {
        // The surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}

     private void releaseCamera(){
    if(camera != null){
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    refreshCamera();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Stop the preview and release the camera
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

}

Help guys...
Thanks...

Comment: Frequently, that means that another app is using the camera. This can happen if your app opens the camera but fails to close it properly. Try rebooting your device and see if the problem clears up.

Comment: @CommonsWare...I am using the android studio emulator, and I switched off the device and started again but the app still crush...

Comment: any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Does your emulator have a camera? Did you aquire the camera permission first?

Comment: @JonasKöritz ... Yes, the emulator have the camera and yes I did request permission in the manifest for the camera...

Comment: What is the target SDK and whats the android version running on the emulator?

Comment: @JonasKöritz... the target SDK is 24 and the mininum SDK is 21. And the emulator is runing API 24 version. Thanks for the replys....

Comment: did you request runtime permission to use the camera?

Comment: how do I do that? I only requested permission on manifest.xml and I don't know how do I request runtime permission to use the camera! How me how please

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to request the permission at runtime. See [The Android Developers Homepage](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more information on this topic.
Requesting runtime permissions is required when targeting Android 6.0 or later.